# How to implement Task.Map

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#

Have I correctly implemented `map` for `Task`?

```
let map continuation (t: Task<'A>) =
    t.ContinueWith(fun (antecedent: Task<'A>) ->
        if  antecedent.Status <> TaskStatus.Canceled &&
            antecedent.Status <> TaskStatus.Faulted then
            continuation antecedent.Result
        else
            raise antecedent.Exception // must I?
    )
```

I got the `TaskStatus` checks from [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/chaining-tasks-by-using-continuation-tasks). I feel most uncertain about `raise antecedent.Exception`, but I can't think of another way to handle it.

---

As background, yes I'm aware of `Async`, but my current stack uses Entity Framework and Blazor, so I have a backend that uses things like `.ToListAsync()` and a front end in C#, so I'd rather just not deal with converting from `Task` to `Async` then back again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FsToolkit.ErrorHandling](https://demystifyfp.gitbook.io/) implements it [here](https://github.com/demystifyfp/FsToolkit.ErrorHandling/blob/master/src/FsToolkit.ErrorHandling.TaskResult/Task.fs). I'll paste the current version below as it's quite short. It uses the [TaskBuilder library](https://github.com/rspeele/TaskBuilder.fs) Aaron mentioned.

```
module Task =
  let singleton value = value |> Task.FromResult

  let bind (f : 'a -> Task<'b>) (x : Task<'a>) = task {
      let! x = x
      return! f x
  }

  let map f x = x |> bind (f >> singleton)
```

---

Additionally, [FSharpPlus](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharpPlus) has an independent implementation of `Task.map` [here](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharpPlus/blob/357e2d2b85e046f50a6ba0de4a4c4b547679ebc3/src/FSharpPlus/Extensions/Task.fs#L18).

Comment: Can you update your answer? F#+ latest version [deals with errors, short-circuits and cancellations](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharpPlus/blob/357e2d2b85e046f50a6ba0de4a4c4b547679ebc3/src/FSharpPlus/Extensions/Task.fs#L18). And it doesn't rely on taskbuilder.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest implementing your solution in terms of the interfaces behind the concept of `awaitable` in the TPL, namely `INotifyCompletion` and `ICriticalNotifyCompletion`.  Also, to implement `map` correctly, you should really do it in terms of `bind`.  This is something that there are already some existing solutions for in F#, such as the [TaskBuilder](https://github.com/rspeele/TaskBuilder.fs) library.  Personally, I have been using the following in a library for years without any issues:

```
open System.Runtime.CompilerServices
open System.Threading.Tasks

type TaskStep<'result> =
| Value of 'result
| AsyncValue of 'result Task
| Continuation of ICriticalNotifyCompletion * (unit -> 'result TaskStep)
and StateMachine<'a>(firstStep) as this =
    let methodBuilder = AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<'a Task>()
    let mutable continuation = fun () -> firstStep
    let nextAwaitable() =
        try
            match continuation() with
            | Value r ->
                methodBuilder.SetResult(Task.FromResult(r))
                null
            | AsyncValue t ->
                methodBuilder.SetResult(t)
                null
            | Continuation (await, next) ->
                continuation <- next
                await
        with
        | exn ->
            methodBuilder.SetException(exn)
            null
    let mutable self = this

    member __.Run() =
        methodBuilder.Start(&self)
        methodBuilder.Task

    interface IAsyncStateMachine with
        member __.MoveNext() =
            let mutable await = nextAwaitable()
            if not (isNull await) then
                methodBuilder.AwaitUnsafeOnCompleted(&await, &self)    
        member __.SetStateMachine(_) = 
            () 

type Binder<'out> =
    static member inline GenericAwait< ^abl, ^awt, ^inp
                                        when ^abl : (member GetAwaiter : unit -> ^awt)
                                        and ^awt :> ICriticalNotifyCompletion 
                                        and ^awt : (member get_IsCompleted : unit -> bool)
                                        and ^awt : (member GetResult : unit -> ^inp) >
        (abl : ^abl, continuation : ^inp -> 'out TaskStep) : 'out TaskStep =
            let awt = (^abl : (member GetAwaiter : unit -> ^awt)(abl))
            if (^awt : (member get_IsCompleted : unit -> bool)(awt)) 
            then continuation (^awt : (member GetResult : unit -> ^inp)(awt))
            else Continuation (awt, fun () -> continuation (^awt : (member GetResult : unit -> ^inp)(awt)))

module TaskStep =
    let inline bind f step : TaskStep<'a> =
        Binder<'a>.GenericAwait(step, f)

    let inline toTask (step: TaskStep<'a>) =
        try
            match step with
            | Value x -> Task.FromResult(x)
            | AsyncValue t -> t
            | Continuation _ as step -> StateMachine<'a>(step).Run().Unwrap()
        with
        | exn ->
            let src = new TaskCompletionSource<_>()
            src.SetException(exn)
            src.Task

module Task =
    let inline bind f task : Task<'a> =
        TaskStep.bind f task |> TaskStep.toTask

    let inline map f task : Task<'b> =
        bind (f >> Value) task
```

Answer (score 0):

Throwing the exception again in the continuation would make for an incorrect stack trace. 
It's a mapping from `'A -> 'B`, so it's probably best to lay it out explicitly.

```
let rec map (continuation: 'A -> 'B) (t: Task<'A>) =
    let rec map_resolved (task: Task<'A>) = 
        match task.Status with 
        | TaskStatus.RanToCompletion -> Task.FromResult(continuation task.Result)
        | TaskStatus.Faulted         -> Task.FromException<'B>(task.Exception)
        | TaskStatus.Canceled        -> Task.FromCanceled<'B>(CancellationToken.None)
        | _                          -> task.ContinueWith(map_resolved).Unwrap()
    map_resolved t
```